# Bubble sorting an array in C in a separate function

Tags: c

I would like to sort an array of floats using bubble sort in C. I would like this function to return this sorted array, and be assigned to my variable testSorted. However, when I print testSorted the output is 0.0000. Can anyone please help out here?

```
    float * bubbleSort(float statsArray[], int n){
    
            float swap;
    
            for ( int a = 0;  a < n-1; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < n - a - 1; b++)
                {
                    if (statsArray[b] < statsArray[b+1])
                    {
                        swap  = statsArray[b];
                        statsArray[b] = statsArray[b+1];
                        statsArray[b+1] = swap;
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
            return statsArray;
    }
    
    void main() {
    
      float test[SIZE] = { 34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                           114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                           200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                           201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                           7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};
    
      /*  Variable Declarations */
    
      float average;
      float * testSorted;
      int p;
      float maximum, minimum;
    
      p = 40;
    
      testSorted =  bubbleSort(test, p);
      printf(testSorted);

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot simply `printf(float_array)`. You should consider writing a loop to print the elements individually with `%f` placeholder in the format

Comment: What else did you expect it to print?

Answer (score 1):

`printf(testSorted);` is quite broken, because the first argument of printf is supposed to be a pointer to a `char *` format string, not an array of floats.

Instead, to print an array, you need to do something like the following:

```
printf("{ ");
for (int a = 0; a < SIZE; a++) {
  printf("%f ", test[a]);
}
printf("}");
```